# How does current density depend on diameter of wire?

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance, electronics

I understand Current density $J =n e  v$ [$n=$ carrier concentration per unit volume, $e=$ charge on electron, $v=$ drift velocity]
Which is independent of area of cross section of wire (and hence the diameter)

However, the book practical electronics for beginners quotes that:

> Current density within a copper wire increase as the diameter of the wire decrease.

Is the book mentioning about varying cross section in the same wire? If yes then can you please explain how does current density increase in a smaller diameter wire?

Comment: The general definition of the density of current is a time dependent vectorial field: $$\mathbf{j}=\mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r},t)$$
So *it depends on the point* you're considering inside the conductor.

Comment: Don't know about your book in particular, but in general, when you read a statement that says _this_ variable changes in such-and-such way when _that_ variable is changed, then it's reasonable to assume that they're holding all the other variables constant. The statement in question says nothing about the total current, so it's probably reasonable to assume that they're changing the cross-section of the wire, but they're keeping the total current the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the book mentioning about varying cross section in the same wire, if yes then can you please explain how does current density increase in a smaller diameter wire?

Yes. To see this, let’s consider a section of wire whose diameter changes from $A_1$ to $A_2$. Remember that the current is the current density times the area, so $I_1=J_1 A_1$ and $I_2=J_2 A_2$. By Kirchoff’s laws $I_1=I_2$ so $$J_1 A_1=J_2 A_2$$ $$J_2=J_1 \frac{A_1}{A_2}$$ so if $A_2<A_1$ then $J_2>J_1$

Notice that your formula doesn’t even come into the picture. However, assuming $n$ is constant (same material) what it implies is that $v$ must increase proportionally as $A$ decreases.

Answer (score 2):

Current density is equal to the current divided by the cross section area: $\vec J = I/A\hat x$ where $\hat x$ is a unit vector pointing in the current's direction. The cross section area is worth $\pi r^2$ for a circular cross section wire. So if the current is fixed to say $I_0$ and one varies $r$, it turns out that $|\vec J|\propto r^{-2}$, so decreasing $r$ increases $|\vec J|$.